# Get __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ to only print the first part of the selector?

Tags: objective-c, macros, selector

Is there a way to make the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro only resolve to the first part of an ObjC selector?

```
-(void)arg1:(int)a1 arg2:(int)a2 arg3:(int)a3 {
     printf("%s\n",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
     /* Prints 'arg1:arg2:arg3'
        I want it to print 'arg1'
      */
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you should edit that string by using something like:

```
NSString *method = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__];
[method substringToIndex:[method rangeOfString:@":"].location];
```

You could then make a macro out of it for easy usage (using `_cmd` gives better results, as noted by [Ole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850797/get-pretty-function-to-only-print-the-first-part-of-the-selector/5850824#5850824))

```
#define __LOG_PRETTY_FUNCTION__ { \
    NSString *method = NSStringFromSelector(_cmd); \
    NSUInteger location = [method rangeOfString:@":"].location; \
    if(location == NSNotFound) NSLog(@"%@", method); \
    else NSLog(@"%@", [method substringToIndex:location]); \
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No. But you could easily write your own macro that takes `_cmd` (one of the two hidden arguments passed to each method), converts it to a string with `NSStringFromSelector()` and parses the string to remove everything after and including the first colon it finds.